# Wordpress The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

So I have a pretty standard Wordpress site setup, however when trying to upload a photo I get an error saying

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads.

I'm running nginx and the user is nginx, I have the user and group of the directory set to nginx.

the directory and all sub-directories is set to 755, and still this error comes up, so i changed the directory permission to 777 to test and still the error pops up.

Obviously this is bad practice and should never be used but i was curious if maybe the user was wrong. I'm running CentOS 6.7

Just for notes the directory is /usr/share/nginx/site/wordpress/wp-content/uploads

please don't comment saying anything about changing the directory to 777.

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of old question but I think it might be helpful for some one like me. I had same issue and I solved it by running following commands from terminal, please note your path of html may differ from mine. You need to figure this out.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

and after it

```
sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/html
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that the user nginx does not have the permission to move the image file. Try changing the permissions of the image file(s), or changing the owner of these files to nginx.

Comment: But its creating the image on the server when I upload it, how can i change the owner of it if its being created by wordpress?

Comment: Can you get show the output of "ls -l image-file-name"? If you don't have access to the command line, you can view the permissions and ownership of the file by using an ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

=> php-fpm needs write access, not nginx. php-fpm process running as uid 1000, not as www-data/apache.

so you could change group like this:
**chgrp -R 1000  /usr/share/nginx/site/wordpress/wp-content/uploads**

ideally you would limit what directory www-data/apache and php-fpm have write access to, Likewise limit it to an upload directory for example in WordPress.